# raspberry pico and circuitpython with ethernet and ntp server sync

Tags: ethernet, pi-pico, ntp

I am trying to built a clock with rpi pico and circuitpython.

For iot connection I use a WIZNET5K module and so I used the adafruit_wiznet5k library. It connects alright.

The next step is to sync the system occasionally with an NTP server. How do I do this? And do I have a choice as to what server to use? Thus far I have searched and found the esp32 lib which I can't use in this occasion or could I?

In any case when trying to use adafruit_ntp.py I get he error :

> File "adafruit_ntp.py", line 49, in **init** TypeError: Provided
> object is not an ESP_SPIcontrol object.

Are there any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the wiznet5k python library already has an [NTP module](https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/wiznet5k/en/latest/api.html#adafruit-wiznet5k-ntp).

I don't have one to test with, but I think the code to use it would go something like this:

```
<other imports for setting up wiznet5k>
import adafruit_wiznet5k.adafruit_wiznet5k_ntp as NTP

<other code for setting up wiznet5k>
currenttime = NTP.NTP(eth, "pool.ntp.org", 0)
```

eth is the configured WIZNET5K device. pool.ntp.org would be the NTP server you choose - you can add country code prefixes, e.g., uk.pool.ntp.org, to get a server closer to home. The third argument is for UTC offset in hours. The function returns seconds since the UNIX epoch (Jan 1 1970).